# How to retain constraints for a Stack View's child after unhiding?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistackview

There's a Stack View which contains three labels and has the following constraints:

- height = 300
- top = Safe Area + 50
- trailing/leading = 0

[image: storyboard]

and the following attributes:

- Axis -> Vertical
- Alignment -> Center
- Distribution -> Equal Spacing

[image: stack view attributes]

Label 3 (blue) has a variation: for Compact height size class Installed attribute is disabled (configured via Attributes Inspector). This makes it hidden in the horizontal orientation on iPhone:

[image: installed variation for compact height trait]

When the app starts all the labels have correct locations on the screen. After rotating to horizontal orientation and back, Label 3 placed in the top left corner of the Stack View while other labels are aligned correctly:

[image: app after rotation]

Xcode View Hierarchy debugger reveals that after reappearing Label 3 doesn't have any `UIStackView` related constraints and the warning next to it says "Position is ambiguous":

[image: initial constraints for Label 3]
[image: missing constraints for Label 3]

It seems that the Label 3 have lost all its constraints related to Stack View after being hidden and shown again.

Comment: Why are you adding constraints directly inside a `UIStackView`? If at all you should add them inside a `UIView` inside the `UIStackView`. But that causes quite a lot of problems. Really you should just have nested `UIStackView`.

Comment: The constraints present are only the ones that define the position of the stack view itself and it’s height. The constraints visible on the debugger screenshots are added dynamically by the framework as I understand. I don’t see why there should be nested stack views as opposed to a single one having 3 labels as children.

Comment: Ah my bad, i thought you were manually adding constraints to all the UILabel elements for some reason.

Comment: @raindev - try to clarify what you're doing.... you said *"Label 3 (blue) has a variation: it's not installed if height trait is Compact making it hidden in the horizontal orientation on iPhone"* --- what constraint are you setting to "make it hidden"? Show your Storyboard layout with all constraints.

Comment: @DonMag, there's a variation of Installed attribute for Compact height size class configured via Attributes Inspector, updated the wording in the question. Added a Storyboard screenshot too. I hope it makes the question clear.

Comment: @raindev - your Storyboard screenshot doesn’t show any constraints on the blue label?

Comment: @DonMag, as you can see in the outline, there are no constraints assigned to any label. The positioning of the labels is controlled by the attributes of the parent stack view. On the screenshots from the View Hierarchy debugger you can see that in runtime labels actually have constraints added by the framework (until being hidden and unhidden that is).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `installed` attribute for that, since that adds/removes views to the superview. This is not good enough for a StackView, since it requires subviews to be added using `addArrangedSubview()`.

An easy solution is to create an outlet for your label, and hide/show it upon rotation:

```
@IBOutlet private var label3: UILabel!

override func willTransition(to newCollection: UITraitCollection, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.willTransition(to: newCollection, with: coordinator)

    label3.isHidden = newCollection.verticalSizeClass == .compact
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Gereon! Could you give some pointers about what `installed` attribute is useful for? Given it's name it's not easy to find information about it on the web and it's not mentioned in the documentation of `UIView`.

Comment: For future references: `willTransition` is an instance method of `UIContentContainer`, a protocol with logic related to size/trait changes implemented by `UIViewController`.

Comment: I can't find any current docs for this, but `installed` is purely an IB concept, not an attribute on UIView. Quoting from this [old doc](https://web.archive.org/web/20160407055559/https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_adaptive_sizes/chapters/EnableAndDisableViews.html): "A runtime object for an uninstalled view is still created. However, the view and any related constraints are not added to the view hierarchy and the view has a superview property of nil. This is different from being hidden. A hidden view is in the view hierarchy along as are any related constraints."

Answer (score 1):

A much, much easier method - set trait variations on the `Hidden` property.

Here is your layout:

[image]

Select the bottom label, and in the Attributes Inspector pane, click the `+` button next to `Hidden`:

[image]

Change the Variation to:

[image]

You now have a new `Hidden` variation which you can select:

[image]

and here's what you get when rotated to **wC hC**:

[image]

As these images show, you even see the results in Storyboard... no waiting for code at run-time.

Comment: Thanks for another great answer! A quote from `UIStackView`'s documentation: "The stack view automatically updates its layout whenever views are added, removed or inserted into the `arrangedSubviews` array, or whenever one of the arranged subviews’s `isHidden` property changes." Since the child view is never removed from `arrangedSubviews`, there's no issues when it's added back as a subview of `UIStackView` without updating `arrangedSubviews`.